# How to make baton passing synchronization using MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

Do a baton passing synchronization - the baton is a boolean or integer value, initialized to 1 ant rank 0 and to 0 at every other process
then modify the loop so that :
each process (except 0) waits to receive the baton, then prints and sends the baton to rank+1 (except for process size-1).
the code now looks like: receive(baton from rank-1) : if (baton) print; send baton to rank+1; baton=0;
Do we still need to loop to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int rank;
    int size;
    int i=0;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(i==rank)
        {
            printf( "Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size );

        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I have been having a lot of trouble knowing how to start coding for the baton passing synchronization. Right now when I execute the code from above it doesn't do it in order and that is what I'm trying to achieve with the baton passing synchronization.

Comment: there is no send/receive in your code, so there is obviously no synchronization. That being said, outputs will be generally interleaved so `printf()` is not the right way to assess (lack of) synchronization.

Comment: Note that even if your baton passing is done correctly, the print statements may be out of order. They depend largely on the OS, not just your program.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question: the each process does a receive call, then a send call. And that's it. The loop disappears because each iteration is done by a different process.